Minecraft server hosted on a WireGuard connection not working as expected
I can't currently use my own IP address to host my Minecraft server because my ISP doesn't allow users to port forward.
So, I followed this guide to set up a public IP for my Minecraft server as a workaround. I want users to connect to the VPS's public IP and have all their packets on port 25565 sent to the Minecraft server at my actual IP address through WireGuard.
I got to the point where I could verify that the WireGuard connection works:
Checking on the Minecraft server:

Checking on the WireGuard server:

But I'm getting a getsockopt error when I try to connect to the server on my PC.
What happens when I try to connect:

Minecraft server's WireGuard config:

WireGuard server's config:

The WireGuard server is running on a B1S Azure VPS on Ubuntu 22.04 and the Minecraft fabric server is on my PC hosted on VirtualBox as a VM also on Ubuntu 22.04.
I've checked if the ports on the VPS were actually open and they were.

Any idea on where I should start to tackle this? I'm not very familiar with setting up both Ubuntu and VirtualBox.

Does your Minecraft server machine have a route to the WireGuard IP range? In general start with either that directly, or with looking with tcpdump/Wireshark where the packets do go.

How should I do both of those?

Start with a tcpdump -n -i wg0 "port 25565" on the Minecraft server, to make sure it at least receives the initial packets from client (there's no need to open it in Azure; it doesn't see tunneled packets, it only sees the tunnel itself) and also whether it tries to reply.

Nope, no packets captured

I was seeing that packets were being received on port 25565 on the WireGuard server by running that command, but not on the Minecraft server. I asked ChatGPT on what to do and it recommended that I make a new iptables rule sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT on the WireGuard server side which seems to make it work now.
